# Can you change a table background attribute with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background, html-table

How can I change the background attribute of a table with JQuery?

I do not want to use the style.background attribute. It needs to be the background attribute of the table. Yes, I know this is deprecated but I'm working with Google's Caja and that strips out any background-image CSS properties, but not backgrounds in tables. All very odd but I'd like to get this working.

I need:

```
<table background="image.png" border="1" bordercolor="#888" cellspacing="0" >
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 60px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 60px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
$table.attr('background', newImageUrl)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code after giving the id **tid** to table

```
document.getElementById("tid").style.backgroundImage="url('URL of the image')";
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pNkBZ/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add the id to the table, then use

```
document.getElementById('myawesometableid').setAttribute('background', 'image.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help  you

```
$('#tableId').css('background-image', ImageUrl);
```

[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

or using JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("tableId").style.backgroundImage="url('ImageUrl.png')";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.css` method can be handy.

```
$('table').css("background-color", "#000000");
```